# alexa handler syntax for launchRequest

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I saw this sample code and do not understand the syntax:

```
const newSessionHandler = {
    LaunchRequest() {
        this.handler.state = "ASKMODE";
        this.emit(":ask", "Welcome to Custom Alexa skill, are you ready to begin?");
    }
};
```

Here `LaunchRequest` is not a function call and it is not a function definition as there is no keyword `function`. So what is it?

I understand the following format in which `LaunchRequest` is a key:

```
const newSessionHandler = {
    LaunchRequest: function() {
        this.handler.state = "ASKMODE";
        this.emit(":ask", "Welcome to Custom Alexa skill, are you ready to begin?");
    }
};
```

Another question: Are `LaunchRequest`, `NewSession`, Unhandled all built-in events in nodejs alexa-sdk? Is there a document for all the built-in events in alexa-sdk?

Comment: The Alexa SDK docs are all up on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs), but the docs you might be looking for are for those request types (like `LaunchRequest`) which are on the [Alexa developer site](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html).

Comment: The Alexa developer site does not mention NewSession, Unhandled events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to ES 6, new way to declare functions within Objects.

It is implicitly adding **function** keyword over there.

Learn more on ES6 function declarations, and specifically the difference between using Explicit '**function**' and `() => {}`, where you will have problem with '**this**' keyword.

In the new form of function declaration **()=>{}**, this will refer to its parent scope and not the calling function.